# How to initialize List of List of HashMaps in one line?

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

I need to create an object which holds the value like [[{IMEI=49015420323751}], [{PIN=538000001}]] for converting it into JSON.

For now what I am doing is

```
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> Request_Identifiers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map1.put("IMEI","49015420323751");
        list1.add(map1);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map2.put("PIN","538000001");
        list2.add(map2);

        Request_Identifiers.add(list1);    
        Request_Identifiers.add(list2);
```

But I need to do it now in Constructor (like how I can initialize a string array new String[]{"blocked","suspended","classmask"}) or write a setter method for this. How to do that ? I am really confused. I would be glad if any one can help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I need to create a JSON object in java to pass with a request in java which is like

```
        {
            "attributes": ["blocked", "suspended"],
            "authPolicy":  ["device_valid"],
            "identity":  "first_id",
            "encoding": "default",
            "identifiers":
            [
                [
                    {"PIN": "234576"},
                    {"IMEI": "49015420323751"}
                ],
                [
                    {"PIN": "68000001"}
                ]
            ]
        }
```

So I was writing a java class and was planning to convert to json format using gson

```
        class RequestBody
        {
            String[] Request_Attributes;
            String[] Request_Policies;
            String Request_Identity;
            String Request_Encoding;        
            Boolean Auth_Client;
            Boolean Handle_429;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> Request_Identifiers;
            public RequestBody()
            {
                Request_Attributes = new String[]{"blocked","suspended","classmask"};
                Request_Policies =  new String[]{"bbm_meetings"};
                Request_Identity = "first_id";
                Request_Encoding = "default";       
                Auth_Client = true;
                Handle_429 = true;
            }
        }



        //System.out.println(RequestBody.Request_Identity);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new RequestBody()));
```

I do not know if that is going to work or not but that was the approach to the problem for now.

Sorry if this seems too rudimentary, I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: You can always package up the code you posted as a method that returns the list of list of maps. It looks like it could be a `static` method, so there would be no issue in calling it from within a constructor. What problem are you actually trying to solve? By the way: you should declare the type of `Request_Identifiers` to be `List<List<Map<String, String>>>`; using concrete classes in the type prevents you from using things like `Arrays.asList()`, which returns a `List` that is not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a `Request_Identifiers` `Class` instead to hold that informations.

Comment: This:

ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>
is an awful syntax that is going to bite you in the...

Please, tell us what kind of a problem you are trying to solve so we can suggest a cleaner approach than the one you are trying to use at the moment.

Comment: I would actually create a builder for such object and add whatever properties you need to. Just a side note: naming conventions you are using (Request_Attributes etc.) are not Java ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is just to get it all onto a few lines, you can use [double brace / instance initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).

```
// Could be one line, but formatted for (some) readability
ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> Request_Identifiers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>{
    {
      add(new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>{{ add( new HashMap<String,String>{{ put("IMEI","49015420323751"); }}; ); }});
      add(new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>{{ add( new HashMap<String,String>{{ put("PIN","538000001"); }}; ); }});
    }
};
```

This is obviously not terribly readable or maintainable. If you want to provide an easier way to access your data, following good OO design patterns and creating a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) data object that maps to your model it would be a better approach.

```
// handle your arrays/maps internally as part of the constructor
RequestIdentifiers requestIdentifiers = new RequestIdentifiers( "49015420323751", "538000001" );
```

Comment: Though it saves a few key strokes, the code looks very bad.. But great technique. +1 for that

Comment: Ha, the request was for one line, not pretty code :P

Comment: Doublesharp - would you like your coworkers to write such code? I think it is always good to educate people when you see something like this :)

Comment: I actually just added to my answer recommending using a POJO for the model instead.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that to the list you are trying to create.. you have to use the method `add` to insert values into the list. Lists cannot be created like anonymous arrays.

Though, you can use `Arrays.asList(T...)`, it is not quite advisable in your case, though you can create Lists like this

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(T...),Arrays.asList(T...),Arrays.asList(T...))
```

at the end of the day, you have to create a map, which you cannot do so, like this.

Comment: There's always `Arrays.asList()` to create a list on the fly.

Comment: @TedHopp But as he wants to create a list of list of list of maps of whatsoever, i gave this answer. But you are right. I should have given a more accurate answers. Thanks for the comment.. :)

Comment: You can use double brace initialization: `new Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>{{ put( "key", "value" ); }};`